# ERRORLEVEL in if statement not works correctly

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

In this batch file ERRORLEVEL is displayed **correctly** (First option returns 1 and the second returns 2):

```
@echo off
choice /C YN /M "Yes or No"
echo The actual errorlevel is: %ERRORLEVEL%
pause
exit
```

But when i try with `if` statements something happens:

```
@echo off
choice /C YN /M "Yes or No"
if (%ERRORLEVEL% == 1) (echo You chose "Yes")
if (%ERRORLEVEL% == 2) (echo You chose "No")
pause
exit
```

**Here no message is displayed...** Any help? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Type `if /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the help text to find out the correct syntax!

Comment: `(1` will never be equal to `1)`

Comment: Stephan, thanks for noticing that. If you don't mind, I added that to my answer explaining the situation a little more verbosely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove parenthesis:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 echo You chose "Yes"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 echo You chose "No"
```

#### Explanation

Unlike langauages like C, Javascript or Python, parenthesis in batch scripts denote blocks of code like `{` and `}`

So putting them around `==` checks is not needed and should not be used. If you want more complex expressions, you would instead probably have to split it into several `if` commands as outlined [in this article about `if`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

**EDIT:**

> As noticed by Stephan :
>
> In this case the mistake is caused by command processor
> understanding `(` and `)` as a part of comparison strings,
> rather than as special characters, and so interpreting
> your statement as comparison between strings `(%ERRORLEVEL%` and `1)`
> so string "`(1`" is compared to "`1)`" - they do not match
> so expression is false, but error is not generated since this is
> technically valid syntax (even though it does not do what you wanted)
>
> You could write `"%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1"` to disambiguate your intentions,
> but really parenthesis should just not be used here

Although parenthesis around `echo` should work in this particular case on modern Windows...

- they are not necessary when only one command is executed, and are usually excluded in such cases in batch scripts
- I recommend to put them on their own lines (except that the opening parenthesis needs to be on the same line as `if` or `for`) to make sure they are not understood as a part of syntax of the command you are executing:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (
    echo You chose "Yes"
)
```

[Here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html) is a more thorough explanation of parenthesis in batch scripts.

#### Additional note on `exit`:

You do not need `exit` at the end of the script unless you want the whole batch execution to be aborted.

This is relevant if one batch script is `call`ed from another, or in a subroutine.

If you want to end execution of your `*.bat` file or subroutine use `goto :eof` (note the colon) - this is similar to placing a label at the very end of the script and jumping to it with `goto`.

However, `exit /b` allows to exit a script and set `ERRORLEVEL` code to a specified value. This only returns from running subroutine or batch-script and not terminates `cmd.exe` as plain `exit` does.

More info on `exit` can be found [here](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)

Comment: Thanks man, i appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome. Based on the comments I added a little more detail in a section denoted by `EDIT:`